# Using cron and a script, how can I get something to be triggered, for example, at 10am, 11 days before the last Tuesday of every month?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, scheduled-task

I'd like to schedule a task to be run a number of seconds, minutes, hours, days or weeks before a specified day of a week in a particular month. Examples would be:

- at 8am, 7 days before the last Tuesday of every month
- at 10am, 11 days before the 2nd Saturday of every month
- at 6pm, 3 days before the last Friday of every month

I'm comfortable setting up cron/at to run jobs on specified days, and realise that if I wanted to run on these kinds of schedules, I'm probably going to have to run a script in conjunction with cron.

Does anyone have an examples of how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first example, 8am 7 days before the last Tuesday of the month, I'd do this:

```
0 8 * * 2 [[ $(date +%m) -eq $(date -d +7days +%m) ]] && [[ $(date +%m) -ne $(date -d +14days +%m) ]] && myscript
```

What that does is run at 8am every Tuesday (`0 8 * * 2`), and then say "if the month 7 days from now is the same as this month" (i.e., this is not the *last* Tuesday of the month) and "if the month 14 days from now is *not* the same as this month" (i.e., this is the second-last Tuesday of the month), then run `myscript`.

This could technically be more efficient -- for example, you *know* that the second-last Tuesday of the month can't be the 1st of the month -- but that just makes it harder to understand. :) Also, depending on exactly which shell cron runs as and so on, there might be some quoting required (`+%m` might need to be `"+%m"`) or you might need to escape the percent sign (i.e. `+%m` might need to be `+\%m`).

Generalising this trick to other days and advance combinations is left as an exercise for the reader.